# Github: separate pull requests for unrelated minor changes?

Tags: git, github

I've only seen Github from the contributor's perspective, so here's a question for maintainers:

When I make a few changes that are all unrelated (like, improve documentation, fix a Rakefile, test and fix a minor bug), is it easier for maintainers if I bundle them into a single pull request (using, say, a `misc-fixes` branch with three unrelated commits), or should I create separate branches with one pull request each?

I'm assuming that as soon as I'm making a major or potentially contentious change, it's better to have a separate pull request for it, so it can be discussed and maintainers don't have to cherry-pick if they want to pull my other changes.  But if the changes are minor, what are the arguments for and against bundling several commits into a `misc-fixes` branch?

Comment: Try the online webapps stack exchange. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming, not websites related to programming.

Comment: @user257493: this is a question about VCS practices (branch per task or one single commit), perfectly valid on SO and has nothing to do with webapps.

Comment: Re "branch per task or one single commit": For the latter case, I was actually thinking of "several commits in a single branch" rather than "one single commit", though I guess it doesn't really matter.  (Will upvote your answer tomorrow, I'm out of votes for today. ^^)

Comment: Re "about VCS practices": Right, perhaps this isn't even github specific.  I've added the git tag for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The branch per task is usually reserver for long development efforts, i.e. requiring several commits each one representing an intermediate stable state of the code base.

But for some quick evolutions that doesn't change the stability of the code (it still compile and pass tests), one commit (and then one pull request) is enough.